Algebraic group linearization (action lift) $G.\tilde{x}$ :How the group action acts on the sections?
I am reading a text about GIT and symplectic reduction, but I feel like some definitions regarding lifted group actions are unclear.
"Since we have assumed that $G$ acts through SL$(n + 1, \mathbb{C})$ the action lifts from $X$ to one covering it on
$\mathcal{O}_X(−1)$. In other words, we don’t just act on the projective space (and $X$
therein) but on the vector space overlying it (and the cone $\tilde{X}$ on $X$ therein).
This is called a linearization of the action."
Later, an example is provided:
"Consider the trivial line bundle
on $\mathbb{C}^{n+1}$ but with a nontrivial linearisation, by composing the $\mathbb{C}^*$-action
on $\mathbb{C}^{n+1}$ by a character $\lambda \mapsto \lambda^{-p}$ of $\mathbb{C}^*$ acting on the fibres of the trivial
line bundle over $\mathbb{C}^{n+1}$."
From this, I understand the action on a section $s(x)$
of the trivial line bundle can be written as:
$$g.s(x)=s(g.x)=(g.x,\lambda^{-p}z)$$
Where $s(x)$ is a global section of the trivial bundle and $z\in \mathbb{C}.$
My question:

How is the group action will act on a section when the line bundle is non-trivial?
What is the rigorous definition of lifting the action to the total space of a non-trivial line bundle?

I’d appreciate some clarification on how the linearisation works for non-trivial bundles, especially in a more formal setting!
